# Need Step by Step Guide to execute the Jmeter Scripts in Jenkins (with Hudson build) over Ubuntu

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm new to `Jenkins` (Hudson Build).

I don't have any Idea how to integrate the `Jmeter` script with `Jenkins` installed over Ubuntu .

I researched a lot, but I could find only the GUI based steps for `Jenkins`.

Can any one please help me with Command line steps to integrate `Jmeter` with `Jenkins`?
I need to integrate the Jmeter as a sepearte task .

I'm using EC2 instance through Putty and Winscp .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JMeter has at least 3 options on how non-GUI execution, all of them are supported by Jenkins:

1. [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
2. [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)
3. [Command line non-GUI launch option](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Feel free to choose the one, you're most comfortable with.

The last one is bundled and doesn't require any 3rd party software or extra configuration.

Just execute JMeter as follows:

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t ${path to your .jmx script} -l ${path to your results file}
```

Just in case - full command line options:

> ```
>     -h, --help
>             print usage information and exit
>     -v, --version
>             print the version information and exit
>     -p, --propfile <argument>
>             the jmeter property file to use
>     -q, --addprop <argument>
>             additional JMeter property file(s)
>     -t, --testfile <argument>
>             the jmeter test(.jmx) file to run
>     -l, --logfile <argument>
>             the file to log samples to
>     -j, --jmeterlogfile <argument>
>             jmeter run log file (jmeter.log)
>     -n, --nongui
>             run JMeter in nongui mode
>     -s, --server
>             run the JMeter server
>     -H, --proxyHost <argument>
>             Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
>     -P, --proxyPort <argument>
>             Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
>     -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
>             Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>     -u, --username <argument>
>             Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
>     -a, --password <argument>
>             Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
>     -J, --jmeterproperty <argument>=<value>
>             Define additional JMeter properties
>     -G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
>             Define Global properties (sent to servers)
>             e.g. -Gport=123                                                                                                                                             
>              or -Gglobal.properties                                                                                                                                     
>     -D, --systemproperty <argument>=<value>                                                                                                                             
>             Define additional system properties                                                                                                                         
>     -S, --systemPropertyFile <argument>
>             additional system property file(s)
>     -L, --loglevel <argument>=<value>
>             [category=]level e.g. jorphan=INFO or jmeter.util=DEBUG
>     -r, --runremote
>             Start remote servers (as defined in remote_hosts)
>     -R, --remotestart <argument>
>             Start these remote servers (overrides remote_hosts)
>     -d, --homedir <argument>
>             the jmeter home directory to use
>     -X, --remoteexit
>             Exit the remote servers at end of test (non-GUI)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Depended on what you want to test. If you want to have a stress test, there is a [jenkins plugin for JMeter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JMeter+Plugin) If you make functional test, just run JMeter script in CLI mode.

Comment: The plug-in now known as 'Performance plugin'. The only purpose of this plugin is to generate performance stats from jmeter reports.

Comment: Due to the new ability of this plugin of handling junit reports as well as jmeter ones, JMeter-plugin has been renamed to Performance plugin.