# Testing RESTful Services : Need suggestions for an Automation Framework

Tags: rest, jmeter

We are currently in the process of identifying a suitable Automation Framework using JMeter for our RESTful APIs. A typical POST Request in our suite would be something as shown below :

**URL** : https://host123.com/createuser

**Message body(JSON)** :

```
 { "UserName" ,"Password","FirstName","LastName","PhoneNumber" }
```

There is an equivalent message body for XML as well

One framework we are interested in as shown :
[image]

The JSON/XML Repository would contain all the XML/JSON message bodies of every unique API Endpoint(We have close to 350 such unique API URLs).

The Test case repository would contain all the relevant tests containing data to be passed into the JSON/XMLs. One such example is shown below :

[image]

JMeter would run these tests and export the response to a file which would be parsed and presented graphically by another reporting plugin/utility.

Could you please let me know if the above data driven framework is suited for Automating RESTful Services ? Also if Jmeter is the ideal tool for performing these tests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regarding the "ideal" but JMeter is definitely capable in helping you automating your scenario.

Some references:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) (depending in what format you have your data) - to read from Test Case Repository
- [Beanshell Pre Processor or Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) combined with i.e. [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to dynamically construct JSON or XML test structures
- [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) - to validate XML response from server
- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) and Assertion (available through JMeter Plugins

Hope this helps

D.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a perfect solution for this.

If you want to automate running JMeter and graphing here are some solutions using Jenkins and the CLI:

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-maven-jenkins/
[Need Step by Step Guide to execute the Jmeter Scripts in Jenkins (with Hudson build) over Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738055/need-step-by-step-guide-to-execute-the-jmeter-scripts-in-jenkins-with-hudson-bu)

Another option is a paid solution with http://BlazeMeter.com which is basically JMeter as a service. They have an API and a Jenkins Plugin as well. A lot simpler but not free.

Lastly, also look at the JMeter plugin project which has some great JMeter extras
http://jmeter-plugins.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Staf/Stax](http://staf.sourceforge.net/index.php) to call XML test cases, run JMeter and collect the results.
Here is a [very good article](http://mordechailehrer.blogspot.com/2009/07/jmeter-remote-execution-log-collection.html) about this.