# How to build JMeter script using .jmx file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jmeter

I have created the .jmx scripts for performance testing and I tried to run through those scripts using GUI mode and NOn-GUI mode in the local system using command window and Jmeter tool and it worked fine.But I want to run this scripts in Jenkins remotely using GitHub.

So is there any possible way for me to run the JMeter scripts in Jenkins.

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
Build step 'Invoke Artifactory Maven 3' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Artifactory Maven 3' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Step by Step Guide to execute the Jmeter Scripts in Jenkins (with Hudson build) over Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738055/need-step-by-step-guide-to-execute-the-jmeter-scripts-in-jenkins-with-hudson-bu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it will be the same, you will just need to add a Jenkins build step in order to fetch the .jmx file from Github prior to running JMeter.

For free-style projects it can be configured in GUI

[image: JMeter Source Code freestyle]

In case of Groovy pipeline it would be something like:

```
git branch: 'some', credentialsId: 'your_credentials_id', url: 'https://github.com/apache/jmeter'
```

References:

- [Jenkins Source Code Management with Git](http://www.mastertheboss.com/cool-stuff/jenkins/jenkins-source-code-management-with-git)
- [Jenkins Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)
- [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins)